# SharePoint site returns 404

Tags: sharepoint-server

I created a web application(SSL) using a previous content database with multiple site collections and subsites, but when I browse to the site I get a 404 error. I can see the site collections from within Central Admin and through the SharePoint Management Shell with `Get-SPSite` and see the Web Application with `Get-SPWebApplication`, but can't browse to the site.

Also tried creating another web application(non SSL) with a new content database with several site collections and get the same result. I can see the site collections from CA and powershell, but get a 404 error when trying to browse the site from the server or a client.

I can see the requests in the IIS logs, but not the ULS logs.

The only web app that works is Central Administration.

Comment: loopback check is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

By clearing the local SharePoint config cache from all front end servers can resolve this issue

Try Below Steps

1. Stop the SharePoint Timer service on each of the servers within the SharePoint farm.
   Click Start -> go to Administrative Tools -> click Services -> Right-click SharePoint Timer Service -> click Stop.
2. Navigate to the folder: %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config
   You will find multiple folders with similarly-formatted names containing files similar such as a326e515-0047-4328-832c-02927b84d98c.

(these folders may be hidden. To enable view hidden folders, in File Explorer, click View and check the box for Hidden Items)

3. Open the relevant folder and delete all files EXCEPT the Cache.ini file. (DO NOT DELETE THIS FILE)
4. The folder should now only have the Cache.ini file.
5. Modify the Cache.ini file by right-clicking and selecting Open With > Notepad
6. Delete the contents of the Cache.ini file (example: 268861346) and replace it with 1.
7. Save and exit the Cache.ini file ( steps 4 - 8 should be executed for each of these folders.)
8. Once steps 4 - 8 are done for each GUID folder on a server, start the SharePoint Timer Service again.
   10 Start the SharePoint Timer service on each of the servers within the SharePoint farm.
   Click Start -> go to Administrative Tools -> click Services -> Right-click SharePoint Timer Service -> click Start.
9. Perform IIS reset and try access you site collection and you not see 404 error.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there are no duplicate root site collection for the web application. If you already have a root site collection and trying to attach a content db that also has a root site collection it may cause issue while browsing the site.

Comment: I've tried attaching a known good content db and creating a new content db. Both produce the same result.

Comment: Check the IIS to see if the Web applications is getting created properly. Also you can check AAM settings too.